# Uploading Large(8GB) File Issue using Weka

Tags: dataset, weka

I am trying to upload a 8GB file to weka for usage of Apriori Algorithm. The server configuration is as follows :- 
 Its 8 processor server with 4 cores in each physical address space = 40bits and virtual address space =48 bits. Its a 64 bits processor.

Physical Memory =26GB and SWAP =27GB

JVM = 64bit. We have allocated 32GB for JVM Heap using XmX option. Our concern is that the loading of such a huge file is taking a very long time(around 8 hours) and java is utilizing 107% CPU and  91% memory and it has not shown Out of memory exception and weka is showing reading from file.

Please help me how do I handle huge file and what exactly is happening here?

Reagards, 
Aniket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to Weka, I don't know your data set, or how many elements are in it. The number of elements matter as in a 64b JVM, the pointers are huge, and they add up.

But do NOT create a JVM larger than physical RAM. Swap is simply not an option for Java. A swapping JVM is a dead JVM. Swap is for idle processes rarely used.

Also note that the Xmx value and the physical heap size are not the same, physical size will always be larger than the Xmx size.

You should pre-allocate your JVM heap (Xms == Xmx) and try out various values until MOST of your physical RAM is consumed. This will limit full GCs and memory fragmentation. It also helps (a little) to do this on a fresh system if you're allocating such a large portion of the total memory space.

But whatever you do, do not let Java swap. Swapping and Garbage Collectors do not mix.

Comment: Hey thanks but now we have changed the server and we have a huge server with around 500GB of RAM and 47 processors with 48 bit physical address. We have provided XmX = 100G and Xms = 11G thats the maximum weka can handle. It has not shown any out of mem exception but it was running since last 3 hours. Cant even check logs. The records in the file are as follows :- 
this file has around 322 million . this file has around 6 columns and per row its just 25 chars. Does i/o play any role  in this??